# Django and postgresql running custom query timezone madness

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, python-datetime

I have a real issue with dates and running a custom sql in django with connection.cursor().

Currently every date I display to the end user I convert with .astimezone(timezone) but I have this custom query, that manipulates dates. Here's the query:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', a.date_done) AS date, sum(b.uploads) FROM celery_taskmeta a
INNER JOIN core_taskextend b
ON a.task_id = b.task_id
WHERE a.status = 'SUCCESS'
AND  a.date_done  > (now() - interval '7 days')
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date;
```

The dates returned are +4 hours and normally I would convert as above to get the right date, however when looking in the the db the dates appear to be correct for my timezone. So not sure I understand what's going on. I wasn't sure how to implement the above with the ORM so chose a custom query.

Btw, in my db client `SELECT now();` is set to my time zone correctly. And in django `TIME_ZONE = 'US/Eastern'` and `USE_TZ = True`.

I then tried to pass the timezone to the query like so:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', a.date_done AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern') AS date, sum(b.uploads) FROM celery_taskmeta a
INNER JOIN core_taskextend b
ON a.task_id = b.task_id
WHERE a.status = 'SUCCESS'
AND date_trunc('day', a.date_done AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern') > date_trunc('day', (now() AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern') - interval '2 days')
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date;
```

Which still lead to unexpected results compared to simply running the query via the sql console in my db client. The latter of which looks correct. It seems like django is doing sometime with the time zone.

If someone could she some light, would really be appreciated.

Thanks.